# Fairly new sod dry spots?

Tags: grass, sod

I had new sod installed about 2 months ago, and am getting these weird dry spots. I'm not sure which type of grass it is (Colorado), and they seemed to appear after a few really hot days in the high 90's.

I water about every other day for 15 minutes, and have started soaking the affected areas when I get home from work around 5:00 PM.

Does this just look dormant? The surrounding grass seems to be doing fine. I can see green blades peeking through a bit.

Thank you!

[image: west]
[image: west close]

Comment: Did you plant that tree long enough ago so that the tree had a chance to root yet?

Comment: Peel back a dead section with a spade.  If the soil underneath has compacted or dried out and is no longer in contact with the grass then that's the problem.  Add more soil, reseed, job done

Comment: I wonder if you own a female dog?  A neighbor with a female dog on a leash? Your lawn looks so healthy, cut at a great length.  Healthy lawn that gets peed on the spots will bleach.  An unhealthy lawn that is short and yellow will have spots that are dark green.  Looks like YOU might have a female dog with the spots so close to the house.  Yes?

Answer (score 1):

The best advice I can give you is to re-seed those patches. They may not be healthy for who know why. But with the grass coming in it might be fine giving some time. Otherwise I do not have much to say...